# Static member 'android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE' accessed via instance reference

Tags: java, android

Sorry I didn't quite know how to rephrase the title cause the error isn't very clear.

I keep getting an error message saying `Static member 'android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE' accessed via instance reference` but the problem is the error is very unclear and I don't quite understand what the error means.It pops up twice in my `NavigationDrawerFragment` class file. Here is my code which it pops up in.

```
    public static void saveToPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String preferenceValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(preferenceName,preferenceValue);
        editor.apply();

    }

    public static String readFromPreferences(Context context, String preferenceName, String defaultValue){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getString(preferenceName, defaultValue);
    }
```

What does the error mean and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a static field, so you need to access it via class reference:

```
Context.MODE_PRIVATE
```

instead of:

```
context.MODE_PRIVATE
```

because in the latter case `context` is an instance of `Context` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

`static variables` and `static method` should be accessed through `class name`.
here `MODE_PRIVATE` is constant variable (static, final).

so you need to access as

```
Context.MODE_PRIVATE
```